# Установка Windows после Linux на второй жесткий диск

Tags: linux, windows

Давно задаюсь вопросом установки Windows после Linux. Знаю, что если просто установить Windows, то полетит загрузчик Linux. Сегодня приобрёл второй жесткий диск. И у меня такой вопрос, если я установлю Windows на второй жесткий диск, нужно ли будет производить какие-либо махинации для того, чтобы работал Linux?

Comment: Я в таких случаях  вытаскиваю оснавной жесткий диск на время установки на второй, потом просто вставляю обратно. Но там возможно возникнет неприятность в том, что винда что-то запишит в биос, возможно потом еще с ним повозится

Comment: Если EFI + GPT, всё должно работать безо всяких махинаций.

Comment: отключи диск с линукс на время установки виндовса. у меня загрузчик винды прописался в esp раздел другого диска

Answer (score 0):

Установил Windows на второй жесткий диск. Все настроил. Проверил обе системы, работают без нареканий, никаких проблем не возникло.
Для того, чтобы добавить Windows в GRUB нужно сделать так:

1. Загрузитесь на свой Linux
2. Откройте окно терминала
3. Введите “sudo os-prober”
4. Если у вас определило Windows, введите “sudo update-grub”
5. Перезагружаетесь, заходите в BIOS и ставите приоритет загрузки с жесткого диска, где у вас установлен “Linux” на первое место

Теперь при загрузке будет выбор Linux или Windows